# NULL data converted into '\N' for numeric columns in hive.?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created a hive table which has numeric columns such as double and string columns.My file contains some NULL values for both numeric and string columns. When I try to load a file into this table, NULL values for the numeric columns is replaced by '\N' in file.I know this is hive property that handle null values for numeric type columns but i want to prevent it or Is there any way that i can change NULL into something else instead of '\N'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default `NULL` values are written in the data files as `\N` and `\N`in the data files are being interpreted as `NULL` when querying the data.
This can be overridden by using `TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'=...)`

E.g.
`TBLPROPERTIES('serialization.null.format'='')` means the following:

- An empty field in the data files will be treated as NULL when you query the table
- When inserting rows to the table, NULL values will be written to the data files as empty fields

---

This property can be declared as part of the table creation

```
create table mytable (...)
tblproperties('serialization.null.format'='')
;
```

and can be changed later on

```
alter table mytable set tblproperties('serialization.null.format'='')
;
```